Taking single value from data frame and making it a column in a new data frame, results in appended col names together
data <- read_excel('PNL35.W1 Illumina DNA Prep Workbook_v16_NEW AGM_COVfixed.xlsx', col_names=FALSE)

excelsubset <- data[11:34, c(2,5, 13)]

> head(excelsubset)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  ...2         ...5        ...13

  <chr>        <chr>       <chr>
1 06B06899G-9  PRJNA514285 NA   
2 06B06899G-10 PRJNA514285 NA   
3 06B06899H-1  PRJNA514285 NA   
4 06B06899H-2  PRJNA514285 NA   
5 06B06899H-3  PRJNA514285 NA   
6 06B06899H-4  PRJNA514285 NA 

#now I want to grab only 2 values from "data", and make them columns in "excelsubset"

excelsubset$x <- data[7,3]
excelsubset$x2 <- data[8,3]



> head(excelsubset)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  ...2         ...5        ...13 x$...3 x2$...3
  <chr>        <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <chr>  
1 06B06899G-9  PRJNA514285 NA    45483  BDS    
2 06B06899G-10 PRJNA514285 NA    45483  BDS    
3 06B06899H-1  PRJNA514285 NA    45483  BDS    
4 06B06899H-2  PRJNA514285 NA    45483  BDS    
5 06B06899H-3  PRJNA514285 NA    45483  BDS    
6 06B06899H-4  PRJNA514285 NA    45483  BDS  

Why is R appending the col name from "data" to my new columns "x" and "x2" in steps 3 and 4? Its making downstream renaming impossible.
Adding in claririfcation. If I then.
colnames(excelsubset) <- c("Strain_ID", "Bioproject_ID", "Qubit_Reading", "Sequencing_Date", "Analyst_Sequencing")

I get
> head(excelsubset)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Strain_ID    Bioproject_ID Qubit_Reading Sequencing_Date$...3 Analyst_Sequencing$...3
  <chr>        <chr>         <chr>         <chr>                <chr>                  
1 06B06899G-9  PRJNA514285   NA            07/10/2024           BDS                    
2 06B06899G-10 PRJNA514285   NA            07/10/2024           BDS                    
3 06B06899H-1  PRJNA514285   NA            07/10/2024           BDS                    
4 06B06899H-2  PRJNA514285   NA            07/10/2024           BDS                    
5 06B06899H-3  PRJNA514285   NA            07/10/2024           BDS                    
6 06B06899H-4  PRJNA514285   NA            07/10/2024           BDS  

I am trying to bring over single pieces of information to fill an entire column in my new data frame. The process work fine except R is adding the old column name to my new column name producing "x$...3" in my new data frame instead of just "x".
Why? and how do I stop it?

Can you please add the output of dput(head(excelsubset)) to the question? That'll clear thing up. I am assuming it's a sub matrix within a data frame.

With [, you're subsetting data. With [[, you're getting the element itself.
You'll find a better explanation in this post, but here's an example:
library(tidyverse)
# Some toy data -----------------------------------------------------------
my_data <- starwars[1:5, c(1, 10, 11)]
my_data
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   name           homeworld species
#>   <chr>          <chr>     <chr>  
#> 1 Luke Skywalker Tatooine  Human  
#> 2 C-3PO          Tatooine  Droid  
#> 3 R2-D2          Naboo     Droid  
#> 4 Darth Vader    Tatooine  Human  
#> 5 Leia Organa    Alderaan  Human

Subsetting with [
my_selection <- my_data[4, 1]
my_selection # Selection is a tibble
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   name       
#>   <chr>      
#> 1 Darth Vader

str(my_selection) 
#> tibble [1 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ name: chr "Darth Vader"

# Creating a new column from selection
my_data$column_one <- my_selection

str(my_data) # A tibble, but `column_one` is also a tibble with `..$name` inside!
#> tibble [5 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ name      : chr [1:5] "Luke Skywalker" "C-3PO" "R2-D2" "Darth Vader" ...
#>  $ homeworld : chr [1:5] "Tatooine" "Tatooine" "Naboo" "Tatooine" ...
#>  $ species   : chr [1:5] "Human" "Droid" "Droid" "Human" ...
#>  $ column_one: tibble [5 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ name: chr [1:5] "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" ...

colnames(my_data)
#> [1] "name"       "homeworld"  "species"    "column_one" 

my_data <- rename(my_data, new_name_one = column_one)
my_data
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   name           homeworld species new_name_one$name
#>   <chr>          <chr>     <chr>   <chr>            
#> 1 Luke Skywalker Tatooine  Human   Darth Vader      
#> 2 C-3PO          Tatooine  Droid   Darth Vader      
#> 3 R2-D2          Naboo     Droid   Darth Vader      
#> 4 Darth Vader    Tatooine  Human   Darth Vader      
#> 5 Leia Organa    Alderaan  Human   Darth Vader

Getting the element with [[
my_selection <- my_data[[4, 1]]
my_selection # The element itself - just a `chr`
#> [1] "Darth Vader"

str(my_selection) 
#>  chr "Darth Vader"

# Creating a new column from selection
my_data$column_two <- my_selection

str(my_data) # A tibble, and `column_two` is `chr` ("Darth Vader" recycled five times)
#> tibble [5 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ name        : chr [1:5] "Luke Skywalker" "C-3PO" "R2-D2" "Darth Vader" ...
#>  $ homeworld   : chr [1:5] "Tatooine" "Tatooine" "Naboo" "Tatooine" ...
#>  $ species     : chr [1:5] "Human" "Droid" "Droid" "Human" ...
#>  $ new_name_one: tibble [5 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ name: chr [1:5] "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" ...
#>  $ column_two  : chr [1:5] "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" "Darth Vader" ...

my_data <- rename(my_data, new_name_two = column_two)
my_data
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   name           homeworld species new_name_one$name new_name_two
#>   <chr>          <chr>     <chr>   <chr>             <chr>       
#> 1 Luke Skywalker Tatooine  Human   Darth Vader       Darth Vader 
#> 2 C-3PO          Tatooine  Droid   Darth Vader       Darth Vader 
#> 3 R2-D2          Naboo     Droid   Darth Vader       Darth Vader 
#> 4 Darth Vader    Tatooine  Human   Darth Vader       Darth Vader 
#> 5 Leia Organa    Alderaan  Human   Darth Vader       Darth Vader

Hope it helps!
Created on 2024-07-24 with reprex v2.1.0
